# Order vertices within layers on tripartite igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following dataframe:

```
df<-data.frame(consumed= c("level1_plt1", "level1_plt2", "level1_plt3", "level1_plt3","level1_plt2","level1_plt4","level1_plt5","level1_plt5","level1_plt6","level1_plt7","level1_plt8","level1_plt9","level1_plt10","level1_plt10","level1_plt1","level1_plt1","level1_plt6","level1_plt6","level1_plt9","level1_plt9","level1_plt11","level1_plt11","level1_plt11","level2_lep1","level2_lep4","level2_lep3"),consumer=c("level2_lep1","level2_lep2","level2_lep3","level2_lep2","level2_lep4", "level2_lep4","level2_lep5","level2_lep5","level2_lep6","level2_lep7","level2_lep8","level2_lep9","level2_lep10","level2_lep10","level2_lep8","level2_lep8","level2_lep1","level2_lep1","level2_lep3","level2_lep11","level2_lep12","level2_lep13","level2_lep13", "level3_pst1","level3_pst3","level3_pst4"))
```

And have preformed the following steps to get an igraph tripartite output:

```
links<- 
df%>%
group_by(consumed, consumer) %>% 
summarize(freq=n())

g<- graph_from_data_frame(d=links,directed=FALSE)

layer <- rep(2, length(V(g)$name))
layer[grepl("level1_",V(g)$name)]=1
layer[grepl("level3_",V(g)$name)]=3


names<- V(g)$name
names<-sub("level2_","", names)
names<-sub("level3_","", names)
names<-sub("level1_","", names)
V(g)$name = names


layout = layout_with_sugiyama(g, layers=layer)
E(g)$width <- E(g)$freq
V(g)$vertex_degree <-  degree(g)*7
plot(g,
 layout=cbind(layer,layout$layout[,1]),edge.curved=0,
 vertex.shape=c("square","circle","square")[layer],
 vertex.frame.color = c("darkolivegreen","darkgoldenrod","orange3")
[layer],
 vertex.color=c("olivedrab","goldenrod1","orange1")[layer],
 vertex.label.color="white",
 vertex.label.font=2,
 vertex.size=V(g)$vertex_degree,
 vertex.label.dist=c(0,0,0)[layer],
 vertex.label.degree=0, vertex.label.cex=0.5)
```

[image]

And I would like to do two things to adjust the picture, if possible:

1. Order the layers from the largest shape (highest degree) to smallest shape (smallest degree). For example, in the green layer the order could be as follows: plt9, plt3,plt2,plt11,plt6,plt1,plt7,plt5,plt4,plt10,plt8.
2. Create space between the shapes so that there is no overlap (e.g. lep3 and lep4). I like the current sizes/proportions so I am opposed to making shapes smaller to create space between shapes.
3. Flip the graph and vertex font 90 degrees counter-clockwise so that from bottom to top it would be in the order green layer-->yellow layer-->orange layer. (I guess it is always an option to rotate vertex text and I can rotate the image in word or ppt.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is old, but I hope that the answer will help someone.

Rather than using `layout_with_sugiyama`,  It may be easiest to do this with 
a custom layout. It is not very hard to do so. You already constructed the 
horizontal position with your `layer` variable. To get the vertical positions,
we need to order the vertices by size (vertex_degree) and then allow shape proportional to the size, so we will set the height using cumsum on the vertex_degrees within each layer. After I make the layout the complex call to plot is the same as yours except 
that I swap my custom layout for your call to sugiyama.

```
MyLO = matrix(0, nrow=vcount(g), ncol=2)

## Horizontal position is determined by layer
MyLO[,1] = layer

## Vertical position is determined by sum of sorted vertex_degree
for(i in 1:3) {
    L  = which(layer ==i)
    OL = order(V(g)$vertex_degree[L], decreasing=TRUE)
    MyLO[L[OL],2] = cumsum(V(g)$vertex_degree[L][OL])
}

plot(g, 
 layout=MyLO,  edge.curved=0,
 vertex.shape=c("square","circle","square")[layer],
 vertex.frame.color = c("darkolivegreen","darkgoldenrod","orange3")[layer],
 vertex.color=c("olivedrab","goldenrod1","orange1")[layer],
 vertex.label.color="white",
 vertex.label.font=2,
 vertex.size=V(g)$vertex_degree,
 vertex.label.dist=0,
 vertex.label.degree=0, vertex.label.cex=0.5)
```

[image: plot with layers ordered by vertex degree]

Comment: Thank you for this solution @G5W. Works great and is flexible if the number of vertices change.

Comment: @G5W Thank you, this helped me get exactly what I need!

Comment: @Danielle you can always accept an answer if it was what you were looking for.